# Print strings alongside math results in s// substitution with the /e modifier

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a very simple one liner to find cases of:

```
foo N
```

and replace them with

```
foo N-Y
```

For example, if I had 3 files and they had the following lines in them:

```
foo 5
foo 3
foo 9
```

After the script is run with Y=4, the lines would read:

```
foo 1
foo -1
foo 5
```

I stumbled upon an existing thread that suggested using /e to run code in the replace half of the substitute command and was able to effectively subtract Y from all my matches, but I have no idea how to best print "foo" back into the file since when I try to separate foo and the number into two capture groups and print them back in, perl thinks I am trying to multiply them and wants an operator.

Here's where I'm at:

```
find . -iname "*somematch*" -exec perl -pi -e 's/(Foo *)(\d+)/$1$2-4/e' {} \;
```

Of course this doesn't work, "Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "$1$2." I'm at a loss as to how best to proceed without writing something much longer.

**Edit:** To be more specific, if I have the /e option enabled to be able to perform math in the substitution, is there a simple way to print the string in another capture group in that substitution without it trying to do math to it?

Alternatively, is there a simple way to surgically perform the substitution on only part of the pattern? I tried to combine m// and s/// to achieve the results but ended up getting nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The replacement part is treated as *code* under `/e` so it need be written using legal syntax, like you'd use in a program. Writing `$t$v` isn't legal syntax (`$1$2` in your regex).

One way to concatenate strings is `$t . $v`. Then you also need parenthesis around the addition, since by precedence rules the strings `$1` and `$2` are concatenated first, and that alphanumeric string attempted in addition, drawing a warning. So

```
perl -i -pe's/(Foo *)([0-9]+)/$1.($2-4)/e'
```

I replaced `\d` with `[0-9]` since `\d` matches all kinds of "digits," from all over Unicode, what doesn't seem to be what you need.

---

There is another way if the math comes after the rest of the pattern, as it does in your examples

```
perl -i -pe's/Foo *\K([0-9]+)/$1-4/e'
```

Here the [`\K`](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.12.4/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) is a form of [positive lookbehind](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) which drops all matches previous to that anchor, so they are not consumed. Thus only the `[0-9]+` is replaced, as needed.

Comment: Thank you! The solution of course worked brilliantly, I knew it was something embarassingly simple that was escaping me. Doing the math first and then concatenating the results is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Asterdahl You are welcome :).  This is not embarrassing -- it can confuse as one is inside a regex. Take note of the `\K` facility, it is sometimes extremely useful.  Let me know if questions come up.